# Second Level Cache with Infinispan 13 & Wildfly 26.1.3.Final

Tags: infinispan, wildfly-26

I'm trying to configure second level cache with Infinispan on Wildfly26.1.3 through hibernate persistence.xml & standalone.xml

My persistence.xml has the configurations as follows:

```
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value ="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
```

The application is deployed using war and ear, some samples are

```
 <property
            name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.app-ear.ear#appPersistence_PU.com.entity.ResponseCodes.cfg"
            value="response-codes" />
        <property
            name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.app-ear.ear#appPersistence_PU.com.entity.ActionCodeTable.cfg"
            value="action-codes" />
```

Standalone.xml has:

```
<local-cache name="response-codes" statistics-enabled="false">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="FULL_XA"/>
                    <heap-memory size="500"/>
                    <expiration lifespan="36000000" max-idle="3600000"/>
                </local-cache>


<local-cache name="action-codes" statistics-enabled="false">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="FULL_XA"/>
                    <heap-memory size="15"/>
                    <expiration lifespan="36000000" max-idle="3600000"/>
                    <file-store/>
                </local-cache>
```

Entity class:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "response_codes")
@XmlRootElement
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE, region = "response-codes")
public class ResponseCodes{}
```

The application was successfully deployed, but when I'm trying to test, the cache hit stays 0.

I would be grateful if someone can assist.

Logs:
2023-07-03 23:00:50,302 INFO

```
[org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener] (default task-3) Session Metrics {
    2197300 nanoseconds spent acquiring 8 JDBC connections;
    1160300 nanoseconds spent releasing 8 JDBC connections;
    5234100 nanoseconds spent preparing 12 JDBC statements;
    9218700 nanoseconds spent executing 12 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    448800 nanoseconds spent performing 5 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    257600 nanoseconds spent performing 5 L2C misses;
    17604300 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 8 entities and 0 collections);
    176800 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 1 entities and 1 collections)
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in WildFly 27.0.0.Final
See: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-15433